# Jquery/Javascript check my word is valid or not.

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am designing an simple application, which plays with words. 
every time a user types a word, i need to validate the word that it is proper English word or not. 
my requirement is simple like if i pass a word to a method, it just have to return me true(Valid) or false (invalid)

Can i find any J Query API or even if i get a list of English words as a 
JS-file. I can use it in my application.

Comment: i don;'t know if any plugin are available, anyway we can create our own dictionary in js and check one word is in it , i will share you a link i think may be  it will help you http://jquery-plugins.net/autojs-auto-complete-plugin-from-dictionary

Comment: Define "proper english". There are many dialects of english, each having different set of words, phrases, spellings etc. Would you consider the word, "lol" or "brb" or "http" to be "proper english" or not ?The best resource I can recommend that covers everything is Google's Ngram corpus http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this might be usefule - http://dreamsteep.com/projects/the-english-open-word-list.html

An open list of english words

Comment: I already tried with this. It allows me to download only EOWL , which has words less than 10 characters. Any how will work through it and find it out. Thanks. Any other better suggestions are also welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/zeke/an-array-of-english-words 
This helped me . I used that json file and wrote a simple method to check the validity of the word .

Thanks for the people who commented above :)

Comment: An array of ~275,000 English words ... This will hit the performance really hard

Comment: yes. I post processed it to keep separate file from server for each alphabet and fetch the specific file alone based on the first character.